# Can we develop a website using Html,css and c++

Tags: html, c++, css, frontend, backend

Can we develop a completely working website using only Html,css and c++ , if yes please let me know

I just wanted to know if its possible , also my questions is in what areas can we use c++ as a backend programming language instead of java , can c++ be used for frontend?

Comment: As a *frontend* language, then you can't use C++. There are few browsers that support anything but Javascript, and none that support a compiled language like C++. That would be an enormous security problem, not be dynamic, and generally just a pain in the backside.

Comment: only with [WebAsembly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly)

Comment: On the "backend" it's a different matter, and then the answer is "yes".

Comment: C++ can be used for frontend, but rather as a desktop app. Browsers don't support running C++. At least by default (it can be enabled via some plugin).

Comment: Also note that there are many commonly used webservers written in C, e.g. nginx, apache webserver, lighttpd. And of course everything written in C can be rewritten in C++ (and with some luck straight forward recompiled).

Comment: "Can we develop a completely working website using only Html,css and c++" - Yes.

Comment: C++ can be used to write a server, but not the page itself.

Comment: https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt A lot of people being wrong in these comments. Now, whether it's a good idea or not is a different conversation.

Comment: Reminder:  C++ needs to be compiled to a specific platform and executables may not be compatible across servers, especially if they have different processors.  You'll need to have either the browser build the C++ program, or attach an executable and hope the webmaster doesn't kick you off their server.

Comment: My question is: Why? JavaScript is perfectly fine for web development and isn't *that* hard to learn. It's also the easiest to implement into a web application, IMO. Not the easiest *language* but it's been built side-by-side with browser environments for practically ever now.

Answer (score 3):

[Wt (webtoolkit)](https://github.com/emweb/wt) is the only thing I've seen (so far) that builds a **web**-UI with C++. May be alternative solutions, but I've been wanting to play around with this library for some time. You'll need a reverse-proxy layer like [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) to communicate via FastCGI to wt, or ISAPI for IIS.

[Example](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/tutorial/wt.html):

```
#include <Wt/WApplication.h>
#include <Wt/WBreak.h>
#include <Wt/WContainerWidget.h>
#include <Wt/WLineEdit.h>
#include <Wt/WPushButton.h>
#include <Wt/WText.h>

class HelloApplication : public Wt::WApplication
{
public:
    HelloApplication(const Wt::WEnvironment& env);

private:
    Wt::WLineEdit *nameEdit_;
    Wt::WText *greeting_;
};

HelloApplication::HelloApplication(const Wt::WEnvironment& env)
    : Wt::WApplication(env)
{
    setTitle("Hello world");

    root()->addNew<Wt::WText>("Your name, please? ");
    nameEdit_ = root()->addNew<Wt::WLineEdit>();
    Wt::WPushButton *button = root()->addNew<Wt::WPushButton>("Greet me.");
    root()->addNew<Wt::WBreak>();
    greeting_ = root()->addNew<Wt::WText>();
    auto greet = [this]{
      greeting_->setText("Hello there, " + nameEdit_->text());
    };
    button->clicked().connect(greet);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return Wt::WRun(argc, argv, [](const Wt::WEnvironment& env) {
      return std::make_unique<HelloApplication>(env);
    });
}
```